# Verbatim text in token registers

Tags: tex-core

How can I add verbatim text in a token register (I want to accumulate pieces of code in a toks register and print them in an appendix). In the MWE below if you substitute verbatim text it fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newtoks\test
  \test={one }
  \test=\expandafter{\the\test test}
  \the\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "substitute verbatim text" ? Perhaps you can put the verbatim text in a box `\mybox` and then `\test=\expandafter{\the\test \box\mybox}`

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "substitute verbatim text"? You mean you like to add pieces of code containing `\verb` macros or `verbatim` environments? Or should the text completely be read verbatim? You should add these cases to you MWE. It should always show what doesn't works.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer @Altermundus Sorry if I was not clear, I would like to enclose chunks of verbatim environment texts.

Comment: I would write the code to an external file instead and reread it again when you need it. It avoids this issues and is much faster if you add a lot of material multiple times. Something based on `filecontents`, but which allows to have multiple environments which all write to the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: as we added a verbatim functionality to the `xparse` package, manipulating verbatim text becomes easier. For this to work, you will need a version of `xparse` later than 15/08/2011. I used token lists instead of toks, but that's mostly irrelevant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addverb}{m+v}
  { \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\useverb}{m}
  {
    \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
      { \token_to_str:N \verb + \tl_to_str:N #1 + }
  }
\tl_new:N \test
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \addverb\test+%&#a  b c\+
  \addverb\test?+-*?
  \useverb\test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `\verb` operates by making the first character active and then using that to end the group that restores all of the font changes and category code changes it made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newtoks\test
  \test={\verb~one~ }
  \test=\expandafter{\the\test test}
  \the\test
\end{document}
```

This works since `~` is already active. However, this isn't very useful because the main use of `\verb` is to avoid having to escape things like `%` or `&`. That isn't going to work here since these get tokenized when you put them in a token register. Instead, you should just use `\texttt`.

Answer (score 4):

I would write the code to an external file instead and reread it again when you need it. It avoids this issues and is much faster if you add a lot of material multiple times. Something based on `filecontents` or `VerbatimOut` of `fancyvrb`, but which allows to have multiple environments which all write to the same file:

---

#### Code:

```
% codewrite.sty
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand*\CodeOut{\FV@Environment{}{CodeOut}}

\newwrite\@codewrite
% Or to save an output handle:
%\let\@codewrite\FV@OutFile

\newcommand*\CodeOpenFile[1]{%
    \immediate\openout\@codewrite #1\relax
    \def\CodeOpen@File{#1}%
}

\def\FVB@CodeOut{%
    \@bsphack
    \begingroup
    \FV@UseKeyValues
    \FV@DefineWhiteSpace
    \def\FV@Space{\space}%
    \FV@DefineTabOut
    \def\FV@ProcessLine{\immediate\write\@codewrite}%
    \let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
    %% DG/SR modification begin - May. 18, 1998 (to avoid problems with ligatures)
    \let\@noligs\relax
    %% DG/SR modification end
    \FV@Scan
}
\def\FVE@CodeOut{\endgroup\@esphack}

\newcommand*\ReadCode{\immediate\closeout\@codewrite\input{\CodeOpen@File}}


\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{CodeOut}{CodeOut}{}
```

---

#### Usage Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{codewrite}

\CodeOpenFile{\jobname.cod}

\begin{CodeOut}
   Test
\end{CodeOut}

\begin{document}

\begin{CodeOut}
\begin{verbatim}
    test%^&$%\relax
\end{verbatim}
\end{CodeOut}

\ReadCode

\end{document}
```

There might be a package which does this already.
Note that you can catch the content of a file to a macro using the `catchfile` package.

Comment: You probably right that writing to a file maybe the best possible solution, but I am sure one can get it into toks as well. Is `\ReadCode` supposed to read the file? It does not produce any output in the example.

Comment: @Yiannis: Sorry, I changed a macro name and forgot one instance of it. It is fixed now.